# Add random value on specific field selenium webdriver

Tags: javascript, selenium, random, automation, webdriver

I'm pretty new to Selenium and Java just wanted to know if there's way I can randomly add a value in a specific field, lets say in "Case ID" field I want to generate a random 8 alphanumeric value, below is the xpath of the field I'm referring to:

```
driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//*[@id='case_id']")).size() != 0) {
```

Thanks in Advance,
P

Comment: Is this element an input field?

Comment: Do you mean u have a generate a random alphanumeric string and enter it into Case Id text field

Comment: yes @peetya it is an input field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generate a random alphanumeric string

```
import java.util.UUID

UUID.randomUUID().toString();
```

`randomUUID()` method is used to retrieve a type 4 (pseudo randomly generated) UUID. ex syntax :`046b6c7f-0b8a-43b9-b35d-6489e6daee91`

In your case you want eight digit alphanumeric String so just split the string

```
String arr[]=UUID.randomUUID().toString().split("-");

System.out.print(arr[0]);//046b6c7f
```

Assuming that case id is an input text box just use sendkeys to enter the text into the text box

```
driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//*[@id='case_id']")).sendKeys(arr[0]);
```

Hope this helps you.Kindly get back if i misunderstood ur question or if you need any further help